# Python: default value of function as a function argument

Tags: python, function, arguments, user-defined-functions, default

Suppose I have the function:

```
def myF(a, b):
    return a*b-2*b
```

and let's say that I want a default value for `b` to be `a-1`.

If I write:

```
def myF(a, b=a-1):
    return a*b-2*b
```

I get the error message:

```
NameError: name 'a' is not defined
```

I can use the code below:

```
def myF(a, b):
    return a*b-2*b

def myDefaultF(a):
    return myF(a, a-1)
```

to have `myF` with default value, but I don't like it.

How can I avoid `myDefaultF` and have `myF` with default value `a-1` for `b` without errors?

Comment: Interestigly, you can do this with functions in JS and R.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do the following:

```py
def myF(a, b=None):
    if b is None:
        b = a - 1
    return a * b - 2 * b
```

Answer (score 3):

If you need to have the value of `b` be a function of `a`, but you might need that function to change, you can set the default value of `b` to be a `lambda` function and then check if `b` is callable in the function block.

```py
def myF(a, b=lambda a: a-1):
    if callable(b):
        b = b(a)
    return a * b - 2 * b
```

This allows you to set a different function for `b` on the fly as well.

```py
# pass b as an integer
myF(1, 1)
# returns: -1


# use default function for b
myF(4)
# returns: 6


# set b to be 2*a + 1
myF(3, lambda a: 2*a+1)
# returns: 7
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I know only few thinks about `lambda`. Thank you for the additional information!

Comment: The lambda isn't important. What's important is detecting if b is a callable function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a try-except clause:

```
def myF(a, b=None):
  try:
    return a*b-2*b
  except:
    return a*(a-1)-2*(a-1)
```

Comment: This is not a good practice to suggest as it's an abuse of the exception handling system. Besides a broad `except` clause will catch and silently suppress other errors, such as passing a non-numeric value for `b`. From [The Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/): _"Explicit is better than implicit"_.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I just started python. I didn't know `try` and `except`. Thank you for the additional information!