# When using a function as a default argument, why is that function always called?

Tags: python, function, default-arguments

I want to have a function that I can call it with or without an argument, using another function to get the argument value in case it is missing.

I already tried this:

```
def GetValue():
...

def Process (value = GetValue):
...
```

I tried to call the function `Process` with `Process()` and `Process(105)` but it called the function `GetValue` either way.

Comment: To confirm, is your example really `value=GetValue` or `value=GetValue()`?

Comment: This is a FAQ and your example does not behave as you described. The `GetValue` function would only be called regardless of the actual invocation of `Process` if you had defined it as `def Process(vaue=GetValue())`. Furthermore, your question is not a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). So I am downvoting your question. **Do not waste our time** asking for help with code that is different than your put in your question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: default value of function as a function argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71305358/python-default-value-of-function-as-a-function-argument) or [Python function default argument random value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62412902/python-function-default-argument-random-value)

Answer (score 2):

Anything on the `def` line is executed when the function is defined.  You want to call `GetValue` *inside* the `Process` function so that it’s only called when  the condition is met for a specific argument value:

```
def GetValue():
    ...

def Process(value = None):
    if value is None:
        value = GetValue()
    ...
```

Comment: Your answer is fine but you failed to notice that the question does not actually call `GetValue` when the `Process` function is defined.